# AWS Elasticearch Service (Kibana) SAML Auth with AWS Single Sign On

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I am trying to setup this authentication (new method without cognito) but can't get it working.

I created a custom SAML app in AWS Single Sign on as documented here:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/samlapps.html

And setup SAML on the Elasticsearch Service domain as documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/saml.html

When following the Kibana URL from the Elasticsearch Service console I get redirected properly to AWS SSO but I hit an opendistro error message "SAML authentication error The SAML authentication failed. Please contact your administrator."

Am I missing a step with attribute mapping or something else that is not documented clearly? Has anyone else gotten this to work and what are your configuration settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can "Shift+Click" on the AWS SSO Custom Application to see the assertion before it gets sent to OpenDistro. This helped me find what the username was that I was sending.

I added that username under the AWS ES "SAML master username (optional)" field and I was able to succesfully login using the AWS SSO.

I then went and added a hardcoded group value under the AWS SSO Mappings for that Custom App, added the same string under the AWS ES "SAML master backend role (optional)" and specified under the "Optional SAML Settings" the string I used to map this under "Roles key" so that it matches.

I checked the assertion using the "Shift+Click" and verified that things were looking ok and I had "group" authentication as well :)

I noticed that I did not require the "Application start URL".

All of this is once you have the rest of things correctly configured such as "Application ACS URL", "Application SAML audience" and the others.